# Can't understand clock angle calculation

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In moment.js offical website,there is a script like this:

```
var now = moment(),
second = now.seconds() * 6,
minute = now.minutes() * 6 + second / 60,
hour = ((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;

$('#hour').css("transform", "rotate(" + hour + "deg)");
$('#minute').css("transform", "rotate(" + minute + "deg)");
$('#second').css("transform", "rotate(" + second + "deg)");
```

In the stament,`((now.hours() % 12) / 12) * 360 + 90 + minute / 12;` I can't understand plus 90 here. what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

+90 is to account for the fact that at 0 hours (12 am), the hour hand should not point directly along the positive x-axis but straight up (+90 degrees from the x-axis) in the direction of the positive y-axis.

You should post a link to the original code and include the line numbers where you got that particular code block from.